# Using LINQ, group list of object combination inside another list of objects

Tags: c#, list, linq, object, group

Update: Change class name as ComboProduct and Product for clear

```
public class Product 
{
   public string Name  {get; set;}
}

public class ComboProduct 
{
   public int Id;
   public List<Product> ProductList {get; set;}
}


public class ProductStock
{
     public Product Product  {get; set;}
     public int Quantity {get; set;}
     public double Price {get; set;}
}

public class Result
{
     public int ComboProductId {get; set;}
     public int Quantity {get; set;}
     public double Price {get; set;}
}
```

```
// Example data
Product: A, B, C, D, E,…
ComboProduct: {1, [A , B, C]}

ProductStock:
Product     Quantity     Price
A                    5                  10
A                    60                15
A                    55                 20 
B                    25                  30
B                    9                  35
C                    40                  100
C                    68                  70
C                    27                  90
```

How to use Linq to group ProductStock into a new list of combination like this:

{
ComboProductId,
Price: priceA + priceB + priceC
Quantity: Min(quantityA, quantityB, quantityC)
}

I tried using the c# algorithm but would like help implementing it using Linq.

```
Expected result:
           | ComboProductId   Price       Quantity
(A1,B1,C1) |      1           140         5
(A2,B1,C1) |     1           145         25
(A2,B2,C1) |     1           150         9
…
(A3,B1,C2) |      1           120         25
…
```

Comment: Can you provide us with your c# algorithm? Otherwise, the question is unclear.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried recursive algorithm but I think no need to understand here, I need to help with Linq instead.

Comment: **Can you provide us with your c# algorithm?** Showing us what you have already successfully accomplished is C# (without LINQ) will help us understand your problem, and you are more likely to get a useful answer in return.

Comment: Please also explain your calculations. I see that for the (A1,B1,C1) case, price = the sum of component prices {10, 30, 100}. However, I do not see how you get Quantity = 25 from the component quantities {5, 25, 40}.

Comment: I believe that `.GroupBy()` can be used together with the `.Aggregate()` function to perform repeated cartesian products between multiple groups to achieve the desired results, but I would like to see a clearer explanation of your problem before I expand this to a posted answer.

Comment: (A1,B1,C1) quantity 5 is min value, I’m wrong, just edited. I tried C# algorithm but not completed, need a simpler way. I will finish that and post asap

Comment: The question seems unclear. What do you mean by A1 or B1? there are no A1 in the example data. Also can you give me a full example with the input data and expected output data?

Comment: (Ax, Bx, Cx) are example to understand the combination, output object like this:
{
    classA,
    Price: priceA + priceB + priceC
    Quantity: Min(quantityA, quantityB, quantityC)
}

Comment: Seeing @tn 's answer based on your original post, and comparing it to your new classes, I can't help but wonder if the easier to read classes have convoluted the goal somehow. The introduction of both a stock collection and comboproducts with its own id, would make it a very different scenario from where there  were two objects. The prod instead of string doesn't really matter, but an extra comboProduct certainly does. If the solution provided by TN is the real desired data structure, could you change the structures to comply (names are less important) and accept his solution? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

***Updated answer** This answer reflects changes to the class structure that were made about the same time the original version of this answer (further below) was initially posted.*

To make it easier to track the data feeding the results, I added one property each to the `ProductStock` and `Result` classes. In the initial data, I assigned `ProductStockId` values 1-8 to the OP-supplied data.

```
public class ProductStock
{
    public int ProductStockId {get; set;} // Added
    public Product Product {get; set;}
    public int Quantity {get; set;}
    public double Price {get; set;}
}

public class Result
{
    public int ComboProductId {get; set;}
    public List<ProductStock> StockCombination {get; set;} // Added
    public int Quantity {get; set;}
    public double Price {get; set;}
}
```

The following code will:

1. For each Product in the selected ComboProduct, gather a list of matching ProductStock items.
2. Organize the data as a List of List of List, where:
   (a) The outer list is the product grouping has one item per product.
   (b) The middle list represents all combinations (initially one per stock item in the current product group.
   (c) The inner list represents all of the contributing stock items for this combination (initially just one stock item).
3. Use .Aggregate() to repeatedly perform a cross-product of the initial group with the remaining groups.
   The cross product of N combinations in one group with M combinations in another group will yields N * M new combinations.
   The inner list of contributing stock items will be built up to include items from both contributing combinations.
4. The result at this point will be a List of List of stock items.
   The outer list represents all of the combinations.
   The inner list contains all of the stock items that contribute to this combination.
5. Finally map the combinations to Result objects having the ComboProductId, ProductStock list, minimum Quantity, and total Price.

```
List<Result> results = comboProduct.ProductList
    .Select(p =>
        productStocks
        .Where(ps => ps.Product == p)
        .Select(ps => new List<ProductStock>{ps})
        .ToList()
    )
    .Aggregate((group1, group2) =>
        group1.SelectMany(list1 =>
              group2.Select(list2 =>
                list1.Concat(list2).ToList()
            )
        )
        .ToList()
    )
    .Select(stockCombination => new Result {
        ComboProductId = comboProduct.Id,
        StockCombination = stockCombination,
        Quantity = stockCombination.Min(ps => ps.Quantity),
        Price = stockCombination.Sum(ps => ps.Price)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Results:

| ComboProductId | Stock Items | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | (A1,B4,C6) | 140 | 5 |
| 1 | (A1,B4,C7) | 110 | 5 |
| 1 | (A1,B4,C8) | 130 | 5 |
| 1 | (A1,B5,C6) | 145 | 5 |
| 1 | (A1,B5,C7) | 115 | 5 |
| 1 | (A1,B5,C8) | 135 | 5 |
| 1 | (A2,B4,C6) | 145 | 25 |
| 1 | (A2,B4,C7) | 115 | 25 |
| 1 | (A2,B4,C8) | 135 | 25 |
| 1 | (A2,B5,C6) | 150 | 9 |
| 1 | (A2,B5,C7) | 120 | 9 |
| 1 | (A2,B5,C8) | 140 | 9 |
| 1 | (A3,B4,C6) | 150 | 25 |
| 1 | (A3,B4,C7) | 120 | 25 |
| 1 | (A3,B4,C8) | 140 | 25 |
| 1 | (A3,B5,C6) | 155 | 9 |
| 1 | (A3,B5,C7) | 125 | 9 |
| 1 | (A3,B5,C8) | 145 | 9 |

See [this .NET fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uvvUH0) for a demo that includes additional test data.

---

***Original Answer:** This answer was prepared before the OP performed a major rewrite of the question, changing most of the class names and properties in the process. This answer uses the original posted classes.*

I have two possible solutions. Both start by grouping the initial data items and assigning sequence numbers. Each group can be thought of as a table of items to be cross-joined with every other group. The `.Aggregate()` function is then used to repeatedly apply the cross-join between the groups. The result is then a list of all of the desired combinations.

The difference in the two approaches (below) is that the first approach builds an initial set of `ClassA` result objects within each group, and then generates new combined `ClassA` objects with each class-apply iteration. The second approach just builds up a list of contributing `ClassB` items from the initial data and defers the construction of the final `ClassA` results until all cross-joins are complete.

The end results are identical, but there may be performance differences.

```
List<ClassA> combinations2 = classBList
    .GroupBy(b => b.ClassAItem)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
    .Select(g => g.Select((b, i) =>
        new List<ClassB> {
            new ClassB {
                ClassAItem = b.ClassAItem + (i + 1).ToString(), // Rename
                Quantity = b.Quantity,
                Price = b.Price
            }
        })
        .ToList()
    )
    .Aggregate((group1, group2) =>
        group1.SelectMany(list1 =>
            group2.Select(list2 =>
                list1.Concat(list2).ToList()
            )
        )
        .ToList()
    )
    .Select(list => new ClassA {
         Items = list.Select(item => item.ClassAItem).ToList(),
         Quantity = list.Min(item => item.Quantity),
         Price = list.Sum(item => item.Price)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Results:

| Items | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (A1,B1,C1) | 140 | 5 |
| (A1,B1,C2) | 110 | 5 |
| (A1,B1,C3) | 130 | 5 |
| (A1,B2,C1) | 145 | 5 |
| (A1,B2,C2) | 115 | 5 |
| (A1,B2,C3) | 135 | 5 |
| (A2,B1,C1) | 145 | 25 |
| (A2,B1,C2) | 115 | 25 |
| (A2,B1,C3) | 135 | 25 |
| (A2,B2,C1) | 150 | 9 |
| (A2,B2,C2) | 120 | 9 |
| (A2,B2,C3) | 140 | 9 |
| (A3,B1,C1) | 150 | 25 |
| (A3,B1,C2) | 120 | 25 |
| (A3,B1,C3) | 140 | 25 |
| (A3,B2,C1) | 155 | 9 |
| (A3,B2,C2) | 125 | 9 |
| (A3,B2,C3) | 145 | 9 |

Note that the Quantity value in several of the rows do not match the original post expected results, but I believe these results are correct and the original post expected results are wrong.

See [this .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M5WOLz).

Comment: Thank you very much. Looking at the results, I see that this is exactly what I need. Because I was afraid that it would be difficult for you to understand the problem, I tried to simplify it and edit the question. Very sorry for this, I will learn your algorithm and edit according to the current product classes and update here. One more time thank you very much!

Comment: I think the updated classes with meaningful names make the problem easier to understand, but the changes would require a rewrite of what I posted earlier. The key difference would be the initial selection, Instead of `allProductStick.GroupBy(...)` I would likely start with `comboProduct.ProductList.Select(p => allProductStock.Where(ps => ps.Product = p).Select(p => new List<ProductStock>{ps}).ToList()).ToList()` to produce the initial list of lists of lists, where the outer list is the Product, the middle list is the (initial) combination, and inner list are the (initially single) components.

Comment: ...  That would then be fed into the `.Aggregate()` as before to build out the combinations. Adding an `Id` property to `ProductStock` would help with tracking the combination sources. For now I don't have time for the rewrite, but might get back to it in the next 24 hours.

Comment: If someone else want to take this on, feel free to update the above or post a new reworked answer.

Comment: This answer has been updated with the revised class names and structure (with a couple of tweaks).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirement clearly. Here's how you can do this.

```
 List<Product> products = new List<Product>
    {
        new Product { Name = "A" },
        new Product { Name = "B" },
        new Product { Name = "C" }
        // Add other products as needed
    };

    List<ComboProduct> comboProducts = new List<ComboProduct>
    {
        new ComboProduct { Id = 1, ProductList = new List<Product> { products[0], products[1], products[2] } }
        // Add other combo products as needed
    };

    List<ProductStock> productStocks = new List<ProductStock>
    {
        new ProductStock { Product = products[0], Quantity = 5, Price = 10 },
        new ProductStock { Product = products[0], Quantity = 60, Price = 15 },
        new ProductStock { Product = products[0], Quantity = 55, Price = 20 },
        new ProductStock { Product = products[1], Quantity = 25, Price = 30 },
        new ProductStock { Product = products[1], Quantity = 9, Price = 35 },
        new ProductStock { Product = products[2], Quantity = 40, Price = 100 },
        new ProductStock { Product = products[2], Quantity = 68, Price = 70 },
        new ProductStock { Product = products[2], Quantity = 27, Price = 90 }
        // Add other product stocks as needed
    };

    var result = from comboProduct in comboProducts
                 from productStocksGroup in productStocks
                     .Where(ps => comboProduct.ProductList.Any(cp => cp.Name == ps.Product.Name))
                     .GroupBy(ps => ps.Product.Name)
                 select new Result
                 {
                     ComboProductId = comboProduct.Id,
                     Quantity = productStocksGroup.Min(ps => ps.Quantity),
                     Price = productStocksGroup.Sum(ps => ps.Price)
                 };
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried this method but it's not what I need. I found the direction following @T N's answer and will update this topic soon.